# Programatically Upload Photos to Flickr in ASP.NET without Authorization Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, flickr

I'm trying to upload Photos to Flickr thru ASP.NET file upload control and flickrnet. But the samples under flickrnet.codeplex.com are, redirecting the page to flickr for authorization and come back.

Is there a way to upload the files with out redirecting to authorization page in asp.net C#?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I need it too

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm able to. First you need FlickrManager Instance for that use below code for that

```
 public class FlickrManager
{
    public const string ApiKey = "get it from flickr website";
    public const string SharedSecret = "get it from flickr website";

    public static Flickr GetInstance()
    {
        return new Flickr(ApiKey, SharedSecret);
    }

    public static Flickr GetAuthInstance()
    {
        var f = new Flickr(ApiKey, SharedSecret);
        if (OAuthToken != null)
        {
            f.OAuthAccessToken = OAuthToken.Token;
            f.OAuthAccessTokenSecret = OAuthToken.TokenSecret;
        }
        return f;
    }

    public static OAuthAccessToken OAuthToken
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["OAuthToken"] == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var values = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["OAuthToken"].Values;
            return new OAuthAccessToken
                       {
                           FullName = values["FullName"],
                           Token = values["Token"],
                           TokenSecret = values["TokenSecret"],
                           UserId = values["UserId"],
                           Username = values["Username"]
                       };
        }
        set
        {
            // Stores the authentication token in a cookie which will expire in 1 hour
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("OAuthToken")
            {
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            };
            cookie.Values["FullName"] = value.FullName;
            cookie.Values["Token"] = value.Token;
            cookie.Values["TokenSecret"] = value.TokenSecret;
            cookie.Values["UserId"] = value.UserId;
            cookie.Values["Username"] = value.Username;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Once above Class created, you can start using below method in anywhere in aspx page. Please let me know if you have challenge.

```
 public string FilckerUpload(string url, string title, string description, string tags)
    {
        OAuthAccessToken accessToken = new OAuthAccessToken();
        accessToken.FullName = "your app name";
        accessToken.Token = "get it from Flickr Website for your login";
        accessToken.TokenSecret = "get it from Flickr Website for your login";
        accessToken.UserId = "get it from Flickr Website for your login";
        accessToken.Username = "get it from Flickr Website for your login";
        FlickrManager.OAuthToken = accessToken;
        Flickr flickr = FlickrManager.GetAuthInstance();
        string FileuploadedID = flickr.UploadPicture(@url, title, description, tags, true, false, false);
        PhotoInfo oPhotoInfo = flickr.PhotosGetInfo(FileuploadedID);
        return oPhotoInfo.Small320Url;
    }
```